# Tsql: datediff not working with DEFAULT getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a table with `date` type column and default set to: `getdate()`
But when I try to do `datediff()` on two separated raws, it always gives me 0 or some constant value. How to assign default value of date and perform `datediff()` that will work?

### Example code, that reproduce my problem

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    date DATE DEFAULT getdate() NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Test_id_uindex ON Test (id);
```

Call the below raws with 1 sec delay in between or more

- `INSERT INTO Test(user) VALUES ('Cool1')`
- `INSERT INTO Test(user) VALUES ('Cool2')`

Now look below over the strange outputs of the next queries:

1. `SELECT getdate() as date`

**Output:**

```
date   
2016-12-22 10:42:40
```

2. `SELECT * from Test`

**Output:**

```
id    date          user
1     2016-12-22    Cool    
2     2016-12-22    Cool1
```

And the last one:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  datediff(MILLISECOND, a.date, b.date)
FROM Test a
  JOIN Test b ON a.id = b.id + 1
```

**Output:**

```
id    difTime
2     0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine.  You are confusing the `date` data type with `datetime` or `datetime2`.  Change your table definition to use a type that stores the time along with the date:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    date DATETIME DEFAULT getdate() NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(100)
);
```

This is a natural place for confusion because `GETDATE()` returns a value with a time component.  However, `DATE` doesn't support the time component.

You can also use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, whose name is a bit more evocative of the fact that it returns the time.